# Filter posts date from a dropdown with views

Tags: views

Hello i'm trying to make a dropdown that will allow users to select posts from:
 -a month ago
 -a week ago
 -a day ago
 -an hour ago

Is this possible with views?

I've fillterd with "Node-> Post date" and  an offset of "-1 week" and the operator is "greater than or equal to." but this is giving me only the last week posts. Can this be done with views? or can you tell me another module that is making that?